# Mattermost: How to view list of files uploaded to a channel

Tags: mattermost

Is there a way to view a list of all the files that people have uploaded/attached to a channel?  Perhaps even through the search feature or a slash command?  Or maybe there's a simple plugin that adds this functionality?

As a comparison, this is a basic feature of HipChat and Slack, but I don't see it in Mattermost.  I'm trying out Mattermost Team Edition version 3.6.2.  But for the most part, Mattermost is a great and most welcome app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mattermost currently (version 3.6) does not have any feature or API endpoint to allow listing all attachments in a channel, nor any way of searching for messages with attachments, so this currently isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

Now there is a plugin for that, compatible with versions 5.12+:

https://github.com/Amonith/mattermost-file-list

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, meanwhile there is a comprehensive UI available from the "Search" edit to allow just that:

[image]